# error to add buttons inside scrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, button, uiscrollview

I have a problem with my App (iPhone), I have created
 two VC (centerViewController and buttonsViewController). 
In the .xib of the centerViewController I have a UIScrollView. This ScrollView show the contents of the buttonsViewController. Until here everything it's OK. 
The problem appears when I click some button that scrollView show, then the error is pointing to the main file.

This link shows the error:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/6elkxbzmn9ctzze/Captura_de_pantalla_2013-09-24_a_la(s)_18.41.43.png

Can you help me please?¿

Thanks so much.

Comment: Without error nobody explain you about your problem and real facts behind error.

Comment: This link shows you the error. http://www.mediafire.com/view/6elkxbzmn9ctzze/Captura_de_pantalla_2013-09-24_a_la(s)_18.41.43.png                                             Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your connected IBAction / target selector is not existing in your implementation file. Check the connections and implement the actions correctly. If you did set it up in code, note that you need to write a `:` for every argument in your method, as eg. `@selector(didTouchButton:)`.

Comment: Hello jaydee3, thanks for answer my question. The IBActions and the methods are implementated correctly. Do you have another idea?¿ I don't know what happends. Insert a VC in a scrollView is correct? thank you so much again.